# Probleme in AngularJs ng-view disappears and not showing view

Tags: angularjs

Actually I am programming an angular js app, so I have to show view in **ng-view** div. The div is like:

```
<div  ng-view>

</div>
```

But when the page is loading, the ng-view div disappears, no ng-view div in HTML!

Comment: use ui router and <ui-view> its simpler and follow this link. https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/helloworld

Comment: a question, your ng-view html code, is in a .html that you injects by a custom directive? I had this problem and it solves injecting $route service in the .run method of your main module

Answer (score 0):

A good example: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

make sure you have also ng-app="app" included

Depending on which library you are using make sure you are injecting it to your module!

**angular-route.js**

inject

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

use in html

```
ng-view
```

note: use $routeProvider

for more information: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

**angular-ui-router.js**

inject

```
angular.module('app', ['ui-router']);
```

use in html

```
ui-view
```

note: use $stateProvider

for more information: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: I implemented all your recommendations, but  no result, thanks for your response

Comment: could you please add more code or create a jsfiddle